zsh export env var with dynamic name
Adding this to my zsh config:
set-vars() {
  list="one two"
  for envar in $list
  do
    export "$envar"=$1
  done
}

$ set-vars orange

and getting error:
set-vars:export:4: not valid in this context: one two

printenv one or echo $one doesn't return anything
I saw someone do that in bash config is it not possible with zsh? I thought zsh was more advance than bash not less.

Try list=(one two) OR for envar in $=list. Word-splitting is fundamentally different in zsh (and yes, more advanced). More here.

@Gairfowl can I skip assigning "one two" to var all together? $="one two" doesn't seem to work.

for envar in one two would work. You could also try omitting the loop and using a brace expansion: export {one,two}=$1 .

@Gairfowl oh wow, thanks for all the tips! I'm liking zsh even more now.

@Gairfowl Copy-paste your comments to answer, I will accept since it solved my issue, if you want, of course.

Then I'd have to add a bunch of words :). If you want, you can self-answer with an explanation. You may want to edit your question a bit to include the 'skip assigning' part.

Solutions from @gairfowl:

list=(one two)
for envar in $=list
for envar in one two
export {one,two}=$1


How does $=list work, and in which way is it different to $list?

I think maybe there a mistakes with your code. Where the list is string not actually as list type. To solve this you can use array syntax with parentheses
set-vars() {
  list=("one" "two")  # Create array with proper word separation
  for envar in "${list[@]}"  # Proper array iteration
  do
    export "${envar}"="$1"
  done
}


A simple $list is sufficient here.

one two is not a valid variable name. You have two possibilities:
Either split your list on white space, i.e.
list="one two"
for v in ${(z)list}
do
  ....
done

or make your list an array (which seems to me the more logical datastructure):
list=(one two)
for v in $list
do
  ...
done


Can't find documentation on (z) part, can you give me a link or tell me what to search for?

It's in the man page somewhere below the section Parameter Expansion Flags.  Search for the paragraph titled Lexical word splitting.
